# Youtube iFrame API's cueVideoById not working in mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

I'm working on a website that involves playing segments of embedded Youtube videos on mobile devices. [The API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Queueing_Functions) states that cueVideoById supports defining both startSeconds and endSeconds parameters as long as you do it with the object syntax like so:

```
player.cueVideoById({videoId:String, 
                     startSeconds:Number, 
                     endSeconds:Number, 
                     suggestedQuality:String}):Void
```

This works nicely on desktop browsers, but both in Android and Windows Phone 8 I get the standard Youtube message saying that the video is currently unavailable. If I switch the cueVideoById back to the argument syntax like this, everything works:

```
player.cueVideoById(videoId:String, 
                    startSeconds:Number, 
                    suggestedQuality:String):Void
```

...but then I don't have access to endSeconds anymore. Does anyone know the cause, or even better, a workaround for this? The code I'm using is based on the basic Getting Started example in the API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {

      event.target.cueVideoById("u1zgFlCw8Aw", 10, "medium");   // Works on mobile
      /*
        event.target.cueVideoById({ videoId: "u1zgFlCw8Aw",         // Doesn't work on mobile
                                    startSeconds: "10",
                                    endSeconds: "15",
                                    suggestedQuality: "medium"});
        */
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

}
```

and only the first example works for me now just like you stated in comments.

Answer (score 0):

it is all working for me on android jellybean now ...

I added this:

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

}